# How to install clearlinux gcc in ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

https://github.com/clearlinux-pkgs/gcc

How to compile gcc in ubuntu 20.04 with clearlinux config and patches?

500 Reward to step by step copy/paste tutorial.

I needed this for [How to replace ubuntu 20.04 kernel with clearlinux kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230903/how-to-replace-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-with-clearlinux-kernel)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Do you want to install GCC in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: yes i want to install GCC in ubuntu with clearlinux config.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gcc-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: Also try this. You can config clear linux after that? can't you? Sorry if I am wrong. I am no expert.

Comment: Is downloading Clear Linux [gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm](https://cdn.download.clearlinux.org/releases/33030/clear/x86_64/os/Packages/gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm) then running `sudo alien gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm` then installing with `sudo dpkg -i gcc7_7.5.0-441_amd64.deb` an option? If so, then you can check after installation with `gcc7 -v` see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/2988/968501) for help

Comment: I would suggest @Raffa to write an answer, so you can upvote/award/etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Raffa and i hope @Raffa writes the answer here so i will award him the award.

```
wget https://cdn.download.clearlinux.org/releases/33030/clear/x86_64/os/Packages/gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm
sudo apt install alien git curl
sudo alien gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i gcc7_7.5.0-441_amd64.deb
gcc7 -v
```

Comment: since you've written your own answer and accepted it, best to edit the question as well. I'd suggest replacing "compile" both in the question and in the description with "install"

Comment: Done and added extra information on the usage of `alien`. Thank you to you and thank you to @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you are forced to compile packages from source because they are not readily available in **Ubuntu** package format, which can be really annoying as it is not always a straightforward procedure and can be a lengthy and time consuming process.

While this is the safer option, there is also a quicker alternative, which is converting existing packages from other formats into Ubuntu format with **alien**.

**DESCRIPTION:**

> **alien** is a program that converts between Red Hat rpm, Debian deb, Stampede slp, Slackware tgz, and Solaris pkg file formats. If you want
>   to use a package from another linux distribution than the one you have
>   installed on your system, you can use alien to convert it to your
>   preferred package format and install it. It also supports LSB
>   packages.

**WARNING:**

> alien should not be used to replace important system packages, like
>   init, libc, or other things that are essential for the functioning of
>   your system. Many of these packages are set up differently by the
>   different distributions, and packages from the different distributions
>   cannot be used interchangeably. **In general, if you can't remove a
>   package without breaking your system, don't try to replace it with an
>   alien version**.

Please, read [man alien](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/alien.1p.html) before attempting to use it to know the usage safe limits for **alien**.

---

That being said, **the gcc compiler package** from **Clear Linux** is within the usage safe limits of **alien** and therefore the following procedure should work for installing this package on Ubuntu:

- Install `alien` like so:

```
sudo apt install alien
```

- Download the current gcc.x86_64.rpm package from [Clear Linux -> current -> x86_64 -> os -> Packages](https://cdn.download.clearlinux.org/current/x86_64/os/Packages/) like so:

```
wget https://cdn.download.clearlinux.org/current/x86_64/os/Packages/gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm
```

- Create a `.deb` package from the downloaded `.rpm` package like so:

```
sudo alien gcc7-7.5.0-440.x86_64.rpm
```

- Install the newly created `.deb` package like so:

```
sudo dpkg -i gcc7_7.5.0-441_amd64.deb
```

- Verify that the Clear Linux gcc compiler is installed like so:

```
gcc7 -v
```

which should print this in the output:

```
gcc version 7.5.0 (Clear Linux OS for Intel Architecture)
```

- Done, the package is installed and ready to use.